# Copy sales_flat_quote_item table with foreign keys

Tags: magento-1.9, quote, backup, foreign-key

I need to alter sales_flat_quote_item having large amount of data and do not want to hammer add to cart functionality. Then i have decided to alter table by copying data and structure of table.

Successfully copied indexes and foreign keys with following SQL

```
CREATE TABLE `sales_flat_quote_item_backup` LIKE `sales_flat_quote_item`;
  INSERT INTO `sales_flat_quote_item_backup` SELECT * FROM `sales_flat_quote_item`;
```

And foreign key is added in back up table

```
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_item_backup`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `newconstraint_bk` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_item_id`) REFERENCES `sales_flat_quote_item` (`item_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `newconstraint_bk` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `newconstraint_bk` FOREIGN KEY (`quote_id`) REFERENCES `sales_flat_quote` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `newconstraint_bk` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `core_store` (`store_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

**But add to cart functionality stopped working after renaming table sales_flat_quote_item_backup to sales_flat_quote_item**

Comment: generate any log file at location \var\log?

Answer (score 4):

Probably there is no need to copy keys to the backup table, just store the data. You can create foreign keys when (if) you restore.

Moreover, you're adding foreign key for `parent_item_id` column referencing `item_id` from original table, but should reference it from this new table you're creating, this might be reason of the issue.

So just delete all the keys from the backup.